# App description in Norwegian in iTunes Connect but not showing up in the store

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

In the latest version of my iPhone app I updated the description and translated it into all of the languages my app supports.  My app is now for sale in the App Store and when I look at the page in Norwegian the description is the new description but it is in English.  The description shows up for other languages just fine, but not Norwegian.  I double checked in iTunes Connect and the Norwegian description is there.  What do I do next?

(Note: the binaries didn't change and in the list of supported languages Norwegian is included, this is strictly a problem with the description text.  Also, it's not a sit-and-wait thing because it's been a few days and all my other description show up just fine.)

Comment: Not exactly clear on what your saying. Are you looking to see your App as listed as supporting norwegian language, when you look at your App Store page, or are you looking to see your App Description in Norwegian when looking at it IN the Norwegian App store?

Comment: I'm talking about the app description in Norwegian when I'm looking at it in the Norwegian App store.  Norwegian is listed as a supported language, that works fine.  The problem is that the Norwegian description text that I uploaded in iTunes Connect is not being displayed in the Norwegian store.

Comment: What language code did you use?

Comment: Sorry scratch that last comment, you select the language from the localization menu when you add the App description for language... I would double check that you actually selected Norwegian and that it actually says that on the Norwegian page in upper left in iTunes Connect. If all that is True, then contact iTunes connect support with that issue. Not much else to do on that one.

Comment: I double and triple checked and the Norwegian text is there when Norwegian is selected under "Manage Applications" in iTunes Connect.  I just used the "Contact Us" form under the general errors inquiry.  We'll see if they get back to me.

Comment: I have the same problem in the Japan App Store in my app recently.  It used to be showing up the Japanese description in the Japan App Store, but now it shows up just default English descriptions in the Japan App Store.  Did you solve this issue yet somehow?

Comment: same for me. How have you solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have left a comment above, but my score isn't high enough.  I'd just like to say that I'm also experiencing this problem.

My app started out in the US, but is now in 7 countries.  I've got a different app description specified for each country in iTunesConnect.  Here's what I'm seeing...

Australia, Canada, Great Britain, Sweden, and USA are correctly showing the description for their specific country.

- http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8
- http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8
- http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8
- http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8
- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8

Denmark and Norway are showing the Great Britain description.

- http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8
- http://itunes.apple.com/no/app/field-agent/id364946558?mt=8